# A simpler MSAL.js auth like Google? (without using the caching system)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, google-oauth, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm really struggling with the Microsoft Graph authentication system (compared to Google Auth API).

I just want to use the stored tokens to make API calls (without managing a caching system or whatever).

Here is a simple example with Google that I want to replicate with Microsoft Graph:

```js
  const { google } = require('googleapis');

  const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_REDIRECT_URI,
  );

  const auth = oauth2Client.setCredentials(googleOauthTokens);
  // googleOauthTokens is stored on my DB and doesn't need to change,
  // I got it from the oauth redirect callback using oauth2Client.getToken(req.query.code)

  const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });
  const { data: calendarData } = await calendar.calendarList.list();
  console.log(calendarData);
```

I'm looking to accomplish a similar flow with the Microsoft Authentification Library (`@azure/msal-node`) without having to manage the complexity of maintaing a cache within the `ConfidentialClientApplication`.

Why can't we just use the result of `msalClient.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest)` to set the credentials and start using the Microsoft Graph API?

I looked on all the docs/FAQ of MSAL and couldn't find a single example with a simple implementation!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to configure token caching, MSAL will cache tokens in memory. If you don't cache tokens at all, you are at risk from the Identity Provider (AAD) to throttle you.

`acquireTokenByCode` is not the correct API for what you want. This API is to login users in a web site.

Check out the sample here for what you want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#service--daemon